# DbContext.Database.ExecuteSql: how to pass multiple SqlParameters to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure in a SQL Server database with multiple parameters. I would like to call that store dprocedure using Entity Framework (`dbContext`). The `SqlParameter` are stored in a list.

When doing the following, it I get an error

> The current provider doesn't have a store type mapping for properties of type 'List<SqlParameter>'

```
public int myFunction(string procedureName,
                      List<SqlParameter> parameters = null!)
{
    int affectedRows;

    if (parameters != null) 
        affectedRows = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSql($"{procedureName} {parameters}");
    else 
        affectedRows = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSql($"{procedureName}");

    return affectedRows
}
```

Calling the function with 0 parameters works fine. With parameters, it does not work.

As stated here https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters, I can pass single `SqlParameter` to the function, but how about multiple parameters?

I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Does it work when you create a user-defined function mapping? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping

Comment: Why are you linking to documentation about `FromSql` when your code is using `ExecuteSql`?

Comment: See my blog post here: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/sqlserver/2020/04/20/use-dynamic-sqlparameters-with-fromsql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback.
Following the [instructions](https://erikej.github.io/efcore/sqlserver/2020/04/20/use-dynamic-sqlparameters-with-fromsql.html) of [@EricEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej) my code resulted in this:

```
public static int MyFunction(this DbContext dbContext,
                  string procedureName,
                  // optional:
                  List<SqlParameter> parameters = null!)
{ 
    int affectedRows;

    if (parameters != null)
    {
        string[] parameterPlaceholders = new string[parameters.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterPlaceholders.Length; i++)
                parameterPlaceholders[i] = string.Format("{{{0}}}", i);

        string rawCommand = string.Format("{0} {1}", sp.ProcedureName, string.Join(", ", parameterPlaceholders));

        affectedRows = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(rawCommand, parameters.ToArray());
    }
    else 
        affectedRows = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSql($"{procedureName}");

    return affectedRows
}
```